# chart.js: Disable start animation not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart.js but I can't disable the start or initial loading animation. I used the solutions in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#disabling-animation) but it doens't work. The tooltip animations are disabled but not the start animation (growing graph)

```
my_chart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Label",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(141, 190, 231, 0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(51, 122, 183, 0.5)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(51, 122, 183, 0.5)',
            strokeColor: 'black',
            highlightFill: 'black',
            data: [3.5, 2.3, 4.5, 9.2, 12.4, 17.4, 22.6, 23.9, 13.3, 8.7, 6.5, 4.2]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        animation: false,
    }
});
```

I also used other solutions from stackoverflow questions

```
options: {
    animation: {
        duration: 0
    }
}
```

I use Chart.js (chart.umd.js) v4.3.0.

Comment: Cant reproduce may be because of cache

Comment: Looks working fine. Can you add reproducible code here using inline editor or fiddle?

Comment: I've found the error. My canvas container was in a div like this ```<div style="width: 500px"><canvas></div>. I have added a height an all works fine. I think I had resize effects as a result of the missing height. The graph grew from top left to bottom right.